# Where I can find this anime's ( Kennel Tokorozawa) all English subtitled Episodes? it's an OVA (1992 anime)

Tags: resources

[image: Anime Details]

This is the anime.Its name is "Kennel Tokorozawa" I need to know where I can find this anime's all english subtitled  episodes.

Answer (score 1):

You wont, the [manga on Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/manga.php?id=22396) only has a link to the OVA indicating there is no anime.

Also [Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=22394) shows no English companies associated with the OVA so you're most likely only going to find fan subs on illegal sites

Comment: But i have got some episodes of it on YouTube which are english subtitled. But from where they got this ?

Comment: @HasibRahman most likely re-uploads of the OVA downloaded from a fan subbers's own website or illegal websites which would host fan subbed anime aswell. you can see with [this link to the *Fullmetal Alchemist* manga](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/manga.php?id=2565) that if there was an anime adaptation it would be listed